# Make dynamic expression with Entity Framework and Like

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression

In my project, I am creating at run-time the expressions based on `Entity Framework Core`. The code is part of a Blazor component. I have a few functions based on the type of the variable. For example, I have this function, that is working, to check if a field is equal to a value

```
private class IsEqualsFilter : ObjectFilter
{
    public override bool ValueRequired => true;

    public override bool IsNumberAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsBoolAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsStringAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsDateTimeAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsNonNullableAllowed => true;

    internal IsEqualsFilter(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> GenerateExpression<TModel>(
        string propertyName,
        object value)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e");
        Expression expression = (Expression)parameterExpression;

        string str = propertyName;
        char[] chArray = new char[1] { '.' };

        foreach (string propertyOrFieldName in str.Split(chArray))
            expression = (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, propertyOrFieldName);

        UnaryExpression unaryExpression = !expression.Type.IsEnum ?
                Expression.ConvertChecked(Expression.Constant(value), expression.Type) :
                Expression.ConvertChecked(Expression.Constant(
                (object)Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(expression.Type, value.ToString()))), 
                expression.Type);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(Expression.Equal(expression, unaryExpression), 
            parameterExpression);
    }
}
```

Now, I have another function to check if a field contains a value but this function gives me an error

```
private class ContainsFilter : ObjectFilter
{
    public override bool ValueRequired => true;

    public override bool IsNumberAllowed => false;

    public override bool IsBoolAllowed => false;

    public override bool IsStringAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsDateTimeAllowed => false;

    public override bool IsNonNullableAllowed => true;

    internal ContainsFilter(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> GenerateExpression<TModel>(
        string propertyName,
        object value)
    {
        Expression expression = (Expression)Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e");

        string str = propertyName;
        char[] chArray = new char[1] { '.' };

        foreach (string propertyOrFieldName in str.Split(chArray))
            expression = (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, propertyOrFieldName);

        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant((object)string.Format("%{0}%", value));
            
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions), 
            nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), null, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), 
            expression, constantExpression));
    }
}
```

The error I got is

> System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type
> delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, String paramName)
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[Func`2](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[Func`2](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[Func`2](Expression body,
> ParameterExpression[] parameters)
>
> at PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable.Code.Enumerations.ObjectFilter.ContainsFilter.GenerateExpression[WeatherForecast](String
> propertyName, Object value) in
> C:\Projects\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\Code\Enumerations\ObjectFilter.cs:line
> 347

I follow the signature of the function n`Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>`. How can I change the call using `Like`?

### Update

I tried the code suggested by [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124386/richard-deeming) but I have this error.

> Unhandled exception rendering component: The 'Like' method is not
> supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This
> usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated
> to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments
> so that method can be translated to server.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Like' method is not supported
> because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually
> happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to
> server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so
> that method can be translated to server.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctionsExtensions.LikeCore(String
> matchExpression, String pattern, String escapeCharacter)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctionsExtensions.Like(DbFunctions
> _, String matchExpression, String pattern)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast, PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast,
> PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]]..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[WeatherForecast](IEnumerable`1 source)
> at
> PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable.DataTable`1[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast,
> PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].PerformClientSideDataManipulations() in
> C:\Projects\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\DataTable.razor:line
> 559

[image]

Comment: Are you using the expression inside an EF Core query? or on a client side collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to specify the parameter in the `Expression.Lambda` call:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e");
Expression expression = (Expression)parameterExpression;

string str = propertyName;
char[] chArray = new char[1] { '.' };

foreach (string propertyOrFieldName in str.Split(chArray))
    expression = (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, propertyOrFieldName);

ConstantExpression valueExpression = Expression.Constant((object)string.Format("%{0}%", value));

Expression body = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions), 
    nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), null, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), 
    expression, valueExpression);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(body, parameterExpression);
```

**EDIT:**
I suspect the `Expression.Constant(EF.Functions)` can't be translated to SQL. Fortunately, it's not needed; use `Expression.Default(typeof(DbFunctions))` instead.

```
Expression body = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions), 
    nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), null, Expression.Default(typeof(DbFunctions)), 
    expression, valueExpression);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Try getting the `MethodInfo` explicitly:

```
MethodInfo likeMethod = typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(
    nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) },
    null);

Expression body = Expression.Call(null, 
    likeMethod, Expression.Default(typeof(DbFunctions)), 
    expression, valueExpression);
```

Comment: Thank you @richard-deeming. Unfortunately, I have another error with this code. I updated the post.

Comment: Try with `Expression.Default(typeof(DbFunctions))` instead of `Expression.Constant(EF.Functions)`.

Comment: Nothing, getting the same error

Comment: The code is not a secret. This is the line https://github.com/erossini/BlazorDataTable/blob/c9d4ed893eff0d4cdc411b6bf0bee2a0f66a5827/PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable/Code/Enumerations/ObjectFilter.cs#L352

Comment: Try getting the `MethodInfo`, in case it's trying to call the wrong overload.

Comment: Thanks. Now the problem is where I apply the filter `Items = AllItems.AsQueryable().Where(filterExpression).ToList();` because it raises the same error https://github.com/erossini/BlazorDataTable/blob/c9d4ed893eff0d4cdc411b6bf0bee2a0f66a5827/PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable/DataTable.razor#L559

Comment: Probably because `AllItems` is an `IList<TModel>` rather than an `IQueryable<TModel>`. That forces the evaluation to take place in-memory, rather than being converted to a SQL query.

Comment: @EnricoRossini Your original issue has been solved. *Updating* it is not correct, because the new issue is completely different and unrelated to the original. Please revert the "update" and post new question if you wish. This one is closed.