# Dynamic Expression doesn't support Like

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm creating a DataTable component for Blazor. It is working but I have a problem when I want to filter the data in memory dynamically with `Like` (see the code [here](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorDataTable/blob/422bfe952b3feff4506c4edaf521e0dbb6109e04/PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable/DataTable.razor#L559))

```
public IList<TModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<TModel>();
private IQueryable<TModel> AllItems { get; set; }

if (AllFilterRules.Count == 0) Items = AllItems;
else
{
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>? filterExpression = null;

    foreach (var filterRule in AllFilterRules)
    {
        var filterRuleExpression = filterRule.GenerateExpression();

        if (filterExpression == null) filterExpression = filterRuleExpression;
        else filterExpression = PredicateBuilder.And(filterExpression, filterRuleExpression);
    }

    Items = AllItems.Where(filterExpression).ToList();

    useFilteredResult = true;
}
```

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The 'Like' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Like' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctionsExtensions.LikeCore(String matchExpression, String pattern, String escapeCharacter)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctionsExtensions.Like(DbFunctions _, String matchExpression, String pattern)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast, PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast, PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[WeatherForecast](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable.DataTable`1[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast, PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].PerformClientSideDataManipulations() in C:\Projects\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\DataTable.razor:line 560
>
> at PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable.DataTable`1.d__172[[PSC.Blazor.Examples.Data.WeatherForecast, PSC.Blazor.Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext() in C:\Projects\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\PSC.Blazor.Components.DataTable\DataTable.razor:line 511
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)

The function that creates the expression filter is the following

```
private class ContainsFilter : ObjectFilter
{
    public override bool ValueRequired => true;

    public override bool IsNumberAllowed => false;

    public override bool IsBoolAllowed => false;

    public override bool IsStringAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsDateTimeAllowed => false;

    public override bool IsNonNullableAllowed => true;

    internal ContainsFilter(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> GenerateExpression<TModel>(
        string propertyName,
        object value)
    {
        Expression expression = (Expression)Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e");

        string str = propertyName;
        char[] chArray = new char[1] { '.' };

        foreach (string propertyOrFieldName in str.Split(chArray))
            expression = (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, propertyOrFieldName);

        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant((object)string.Format("%{0}%", value));
            
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions), 
            nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), null, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), 
            expression, constantExpression));
    }
}
```

but I think this function is working well. The problem is when I apply the filter to the `AllItems`.

```
Items = AllItems.Where(filterExpression).ToList();
```

Also, I tried to change this line with

```
Items = new List<TModel>();
var t = AllItems.Where(filterExpression);
foreach (var i in t)
    Items.Add(i);
```

but I get the same result.

### Update

This is the Quick Watch I see for the `filterExpression` variable.
[image]

I have another function for `Equals` and it is working

```
private class IsEqualsFilter : ObjectFilter
{
    public override bool ValueRequired => true;

    public override bool IsNumberAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsBoolAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsStringAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsDateTimeAllowed => true;

    public override bool IsNonNullableAllowed => true;

    internal IsEqualsFilter(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> GenerateExpression<TModel>(
        string propertyName,
        object value)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "e");
        Expression expression = (Expression)parameterExpression;

        string str = propertyName;
        char[] chArray = new char[1] { '.' };

        foreach (string propertyOrFieldName in str.Split(chArray))
            expression = (Expression)Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, propertyOrFieldName);

        UnaryExpression unaryExpression = !expression.Type.IsEnum ?
                Expression.ConvertChecked(Expression.Constant(value), expression.Type) :
                Expression.ConvertChecked(Expression.Constant(
                (object)Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(expression.Type, value.ToString()))), 
                expression.Type);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(Expression.Equal(expression, unaryExpression), 
            parameterExpression);
    }
}
```

### Update/2

As [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124386/richard-deeming) said,  in EF Core 3.1, the DbFunctionExtensions.Like method works with in-memory queries; but the code has since been updated to just throw an InvalidOperationException in [commit](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/47d1ebedf834f1b4caae4d4f45f5f54d788e31af#diff-599daeb8704da4dc22a46e67b8267a07e01e8d3b8c90ae5a10d2b74cbd4cf2ce). The generic implementation with `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>` is working for every kind of `Type` apart from `string`.

So, I add a custom implementation for `string`

```
public override IList<TModel> ApplyEmbeddedFilter<TModel>(IList<TModel> models, 
    string propertyName, string value)
{
    var searchStrLower = value.ToLower();
    var propsToCheck = typeof(TModel).GetProperties()
          .Where(a => a.PropertyType == typeof(string) && 
                 a.Name == propertyName && a.CanRead);

    return models.Where(obj => {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propsToCheck)
        {
            string value = (string)prop.GetValue(obj);
            if (value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchStrLower)) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: How about the exception message, is that unhelpful or unclear?

Comment: Try inspecting filterExpression's `DebugView`: does it contain the `filterExpression` and `filterRuleExpression` parts inline, or does it attempt to invoke another lambda?

Comment: That looks like the original code, not the fixed code from [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930683/make-dynamic-expression-with-entity-framework-and-like).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @RichardDeeming no. As you suggested I changed the `AllItems` in a `IQuerable` but I got the same error.

Comment: Re your update -- look at the `DebugView` property, as I said

Comment: Annoyingly, in EF Core 3.1, the `DbFunctionExtensions.Like` method works with in-memory queries; but the code has since been updated to just throw an `InvalidOperationException` in [commit 47d1ebedf834f1b4caae4d4f45f5f54d788e31af](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/47d1ebedf834f1b4caae4d4f45f5f54d788e31af#diff-599daeb8704da4dc22a46e67b8267a07e01e8d3b8c90ae5a10d2b74cbd4cf2ce).

Comment: What makes me crazy is that ALL the filter with any expressions for every type is working apart from LIKE and `string`

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is not related to dynamic queries. You can reproduce it like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
// ...

IQueryable<string> test = (new[] { "a", "b" }).AsQueryable();
var result = test.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c, "a")).ToArray();
```

This will throw the same exception, and this is kind of query you are dynamically building with expressions in your `ContainsFilter`. The reason is `EF.Functions.Like` is not intended to be used with in-memory collections. It's only purpose is to be analyzed by EF Core expression tree analyzer and be converted to SQL `LIKE` statement. If you execute this function normally (that's what happens when you use it with in-memory collection) it just throws exception:

```
EF.Functions.Like("a", "b"); // throws the same exception
```

So to filter in-memory you need to use something different (maybe just basic `string.Contains` will do, maybe not, we don't know).

Comment: @canton7 OP mentions right at the first line: "but I have a problem when I want to filter the data _in memory_ dynamically with Like". So he reuses filters he uses for database queries to do similar operations in memory.